# Flights with all inclusive stay/living, some jargon for this?

Tags: terminology

Suppose a competition has a prize that contains flight tickets, all food and accommodation. Is there some special term in English to describe it? `Flights with all inclusive stay` or `Flights with all inclusive living`? Or something else? `Luxurious living` is an overkill, how to describe the prize with flights tickets, accommodation and all food covered?

Comment: I've usually seen this called an “all expenses paid trip” or “vacation.”

Comment: @BraddSzonye In this case, it is not really a vacation because the winners represent a country in a competition so naturally they got all expenses covered.

Comment: *All-inclusive* usually covers all travel, meals and accommodations. It's pretty standard. More luxurious trips might include guided tours.

Comment: @Susan so you mean that there must be a dash?

Comment: If you are using it as an adjective, you can use the hyphen (an all-inclusive trip to...) or not; if used after the 'trip/prize/other', then no.

Comment: Even when used predicatively, it is quite common to include the hyphen: _the trip is all-inclusive_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*All-inclusive* can be used in this way, but it can also be used to describe only a hotel stay that includes all meals and other luxuries (spa, Internet, extra cable—what have you). As such, it can perhaps be slightly ambiguous for your particular context on its own. As an eternal sceptic, I would certainly assume that a competition that advertised an all-inclusive holiday really meant an all-inclusive hotel stay where you get to pay for your own tickets.

The combination of buying flight tickets, hotel, local transportation, and everything else in connection with the holiday together as one item is often referred to as a *package deal*.

As such, if you wish to be quite unambiguous, you can advertise that the first prize in the competition is an ***all-inclusive package deal*** to some location or other.

Comment: +1 For "package deal". Worth mentioning that both with that and even things referred to as "all-inclusive", what's *actually* included can vary.

Answer (score 0):

"All expenses paid" or "all-inclusive" are both acceptable terms.